# PHP session resets when i refresh page

Tags: php, session

Hi i'm a noob when it comes to PHP but im making a page where after you login you go to the homepage, but when im at the homepage logged in and refreshes the page i get logged out.

Here the code for my login.
`

```
session_start();

require('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

     $username = $_POST['username'];

     $password = $_POST['password'];


     $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"; 

     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

     header("Location: index.php");

    }else{
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
```

and the code for my index.php

```
<?php 
require'connect.php';
session_start();



if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo" not logged in";


}else {
    echo "logged in";

}   
?>
```

Comment: i think it have to do with ur browser settings

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). As for the session, check `session_id()` on each page. if the id's changing, then something is causing the session cookie to be lost, and a new/empty session to be created each time.

Comment: hi thanks for the answere,i checked the session_id() and it's not changing uppon refresh im afraid.

Comment: @Destoffe if your session id is not changing, then you are not losing your session.

Comment: But how come if im logged in and refreshes the site, the if function changes to not logged in then?

Comment: @Destoffe i can only assume there is more code involved that you haven't provided.

Answer (score 2):

your login page has:

```
session_start();
require('connect.php');
```

whereas your home page has:

```
require'connect.php';
session_start();
```

Try to be consistent. From the [manual](http://php.net/session_start):

> "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser."

Make sure you're calling `session_start()` first, in both pages. Make sure you don't have any white space or anything else being outputted first. For example:

### correct:

```
<?php

session_start();
```

### incorrect:

```
// white space above PHP tag

<?php

session_start();
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I think @mister's solution would have solved your problem but if it doesn't then you need to check your code on all browsers or check php session settings to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small issues as not much of php code is involved here.
Try running this code without

> require('connect.php');

If it still doesn't get resolved, I would recommend you to check with the code in connect.php file.